# what is the md5sum of curl 7.36.0 zip?

Tags: curl, md5sum

i downloaded 2 zip files of `curl` version `7.36.0`, one form the official github and second from the official `haxx` website. but they both have different content, which one shall i use for security reasons? i couldn't find any list of md5sums nowhere.

my output of the files is:

```
~/Desktop $ md5sum curl-*
ac6df62a00196563b92ccd236c36222b  curl-7.36.0.zip //haxx.se website
c3a1a37599f629fd25181d4879add5d1  curl-curl-7_36_0.zip //github
```

when i google the sums, the first does have 2 hits, but the latter seems to be very unique with no results

Comment: Your question could become a programming question if you showed the differences **in content** that you claim there are between the two versions. As the same contents can be zipped to different files with different zip parameters, different md5 hashes do not in themselves demonstrate a difference in contents, and are completely useless as information in a programming-related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github doesn't deliver the same file as the curl web site does. The github one just puts everything that is available in the source tree using that tag, while the *real* download from curl.haxx.se contains the actual release package.

So, the correct 7.36.0 release zip file is:

```
ac6df62a00196563b92ccd236c36222b  curl-7.36.0.zip
```